# Menu Wildcard Argument Displays in Breadcrumb

Tags: routes

So, I have a menu setup in my module like the following. I have omitted most of the definition parameters to be brief:

```
$menu = array(
    'admin/config/people/MY_MODULE' => array(
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      'title' => 'MY MODULE',
    ),
    'admin/config/people/MY_MODULE/list' => array(
      'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
      'title' => 'View Lists'
    ),
    'admin/config/people/MY_MODULE/add' => array(
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'title' => 'Add a list'
    ),
    'admin/config/people/MY_MODULE/%ARG_LOAD/edit' => array(
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'title' => 'Edit a List'
    )
);
```

My problem is primarily for the breadcrumbs. For the first 3 menu items, the breadcrumbs are generated correctly.

So for example, for the first item, `admin/config/people/MY_MODULE`, the breadcrumb is `Home » Administration » Configuration » People`.

For the third item, `admin/config/people/MY_MODULE/add`, the breadcrumb is `Home » Administration » Configuration » People » MY MODULE`.

Take the fourth item though, which contains a wildcard argument. Say I load a path like this: `admin/config/people/MY_MODULE/acme/edit`.

I still expect the breadcrumb to be `Home » Administration » Configuration » People » MY MODULE`.

However it is actually `Home » Administration » Configuration » People » MY MODULE >> MY MODULE` with the trailing `MY MODULE` entry linking to `admin/config/people/MY_MODULE/acme/`.

As you can see, it generated a link to the path ending in the wildcard. So my questions are:

- Why is it doing that?
- How do I stop it from doing it?

What's bothering me is that the Taxonomy module, in Core, defines a similar structure and the breadcrumbs for it are generated correctly. So I know its not a problem with the admin theme in use.

Any thoughts?